# SQL select distinct count division

Tags: sql, division

I have a select statement with a distinct count and I need to divide the result of the select count with a number . How can I do it?
I have for example:

```
select distinct count(profile_entity_name)
from table_name
where visit_id like 'JWM%' and profile_entity_name not in ('JWM 2.0 COM','JWM 2.0 MASTER')
```

and it gives the result 2000
I want to divide the 2000 with 130 for example on the fly

How can I do it?
I tried the whole select with the division at the end '/130' and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an complement to Md. Suman Kabir's Answer, if you want the select to return the exact division, just cast the "count" function and the divisor number as float, like this:

```
    select cast(count(distinct profile_entity_name) as float) / cast(130 as float) from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of `distinct` before `count` has no meaning. Perhaps you want to count distinct `profile_entity_name`, So you can try this :

```
select count(distinct profile_entity_name) / 130 from ....
```

Answer (score 0):

save your result and divide with 130

```
select TB1.[total count]/130  from (select distinct count(profile_entity_name)as[total count]
from table_name
where visit_id like 'JWM%' and profile_entity_name not in ('JWM 2.0 COM','JWM 2.0 MASTER') ) as TB1
```